# Disable Yarn's "Please choose a version of "google-closure-compiler-windows" from this list"

Tags: javascript, node.js, yarnpkg

Every time I install a package with Yarn, it prompts me with "Please choose a version of "google-closure-compiler-windows" from this list:". Is it possible to disable this prompt and always use the latest stable version?

I'm using WSL.